# Excel 2010 Macro to do the same task again and again

Tags: excel, vba

I need to send Sales Report to my colleagues on the end of every week and I pull the same details from SAP (Stockwarehouse Russia). My question is, everytime I need to do the same steps again and again in Excel i.e. editing and deleting the same columns, applying filters, assigning the right description for the exact same fields, Movement Type etc. And it becomes very monotonous and pathetically time consuming.

So is there a way where I can record the steps I performed and store is somewhere on the HDD so that next time I can simply open Excel, run the program and report would be generated automatically?

Answer (score 0):

What you will need to do is record a Macro

http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/create-or-delete-a-macro-HP010342374.aspx

http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-record-a-macro-to-automate-tasks-in-excel-2.html

First 2 links in a Google search...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Excel 2013. I would higly recommend to use Microsoft Power Query AddIn (PQ). With PQ you can easily connect to SAP, than create some transformation with your data and save this as a "script". WHenever you open this worksheet you will have a fresh data. The adventage is that you don't need to use any piece of code and you can save your operation in few minutes. 
Later if you will want to automate this operation you can write simple script (avaliable on the net) to refresh the worksheet and just add the code to send somewhere or if you have a SharePoint you can easily share with your worksheet with Power Query script into the SharePoint and everybody should have acces to your transormed data.

Please check: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/powerBI/SAP.aspx#fbid=OjGdeZslbeu